# Poor video quality in first few frames using video output options in gganimate

Tags: r, ffmpeg, gganimate

I'm trying to export some animations I've made using gganimate through video format as the gifs I'm creating are quite large.

Sample code:

```
library(gganimate)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
  theme_dark() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_line(colour = "white")) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  transition_states(
    gear,
    transition_length = 2,
    state_length = 1
  ) +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_shrink() +
  ease_aes('sine-in-out')

anim_save("example.mp4",
          animate(
            p,
            nframes = 450,
            fps = 25,
            width = 1280,
            height = 720,
            type = "cairo",
            start_pause = 50,
            end_pause = 50,
            renderer = av_renderer()
          ))
```

Produces the video seen here: https://vimeo.com/505019987

With the standard ggplot2 theme: https://vimeo.com/505020822

This is another example of something I made using gganimate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHzjl_z_sSo

You can see that the video quality in the first few frames are very bad. In the video with the standard ggplot2 theme and the YouTube video, the gridlines and watermark text are not visible at the start but fade in much later. I don't know much about video codecs but I assume it has something to do with the ffmpeg library the `av` package/`av_renderer()` is using. Has anyone experienced something like this?

Comment: What are the options supplied to ffmpeg?

Comment: @Gyan there is a `vfilter` argument in the `av_renderer()` function mentioned here https://ropensci.org/technotes/2018/10/06/av-release/ which I think borrows from ffmpeg.